# The search parameter isanswered ignores acceptances

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions, search

The SE definition of "answered" question is: has an answer that is either accepted or has positive score. But the search parameter `isanswered` appears to ignore the "accepted" clause: when set to "no" it still returns questions with an accepted answer, as long as it has 0 score.

[Sample query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=NSWindowController%20%20is%3aquestion%20isanswered%3ano) to reproduce the bug (unless meta effect kicks in and the answers get upvotes).

---

By the way, it seems that `isanswered` works only when `is:question` is present, but I'm not complaining about that... yet.

Also, this parameter is not listed on the [advanced search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but I'm not complaining about that either... yet.

Comment: isanswered works if you're searching for those that aren't unanswered, as the tab defines it

Comment: No. The [unanswered tab](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) does not list questions with an accepted answer. The parameter `isanswered:no` does.

Comment: Here's a sample query that shows all questions with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+isanswered%3A0+hasaccepted%3A1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the flag we use for the unanswered tab. It's just named badly. Consider thinking about it as `hasAnswerWithScoreGreatherThanZero`.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: I was just going to say... what other golden treasures reside in the search queries that we don't know about...?