# The "isanswered" search parameter documentation is incorrect

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, search, unanswered-questions

*Request*: Document the `isanswered` search parameter on the [advanced search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

### Update

This has been implemented by adding the following to the help page:

> isanswered: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one accepted or positively-scored answer; no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted or positively-scored answers.

Unfortunately, the above **[is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250187/259867)**: acceptances are ignored by this search. The correct description would be:

> isanswered: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one positively-scored answer; no/false/0 returns only questions with no positively-scored answers.

---

#### Rationale

From time to time users ask about searching for questions that are unanswered-in-SE-sense (no accepted answer and no positively scored answer). For example, [Deduplicator asked yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for/286915#comment161363_286915):

> What about adding a new operator to search, which restricts the same way as the unanswered page?

The older thread on this is [How to search unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16542/259867) where the answers include: using `hasaccepted:0`, using `answers:0`. There is also a feature request there to have `ascore:0` parameter to handle the presence of answers with positive score.

Yet, all this time SE did have a search parameter for filtering questions based on answer score: `isanswered`. As [m0sa explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250187/259867), its logic is actually `hasAnswerWithScoreGreaterThanZero`

Thus, the combination `isanswered:0 hasaccepted:0 closed:0` matches SE definition of an unanswered question.

For example, [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3A0) nearly matches the [questions/unanswered view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) on Stack Overflow. (The numbers are not exactly the same, either because of caching or because of some narrow edge cases; for practical purposes the results
are the same.

One can now filter by tags and/or question score, then sort by dates, etc... like you always wanted. For example,  when I'm feeling generous, I combine this search with `intags:mine` and `answers:1..` to review answers on unanswered questions and maybe upvote them, taking the question out of unanswered.

Comment: The other option is to fix the search parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the documentation to describe the actual behaviour of the `isanswered` search operator, which does not take the accept status into account.

Comment: hi, I was trying to use the `is:answered` filter and since it was not acting like I expected, I started looking around and it all lead me here, so I tried changing my search criteria and tried `[jquery] created:31d answered:0 is:question` and `[jquery] created:31d answered:...0 is:question` only to be disappointed again: either way results show 1 question, [specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49110377/4770813), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+created%3A31d+answered%3A...0+is%3Aquestion) is the results' url; am I missing something?, again?

Comment: sorry, saw the typo now