# Add an anonymous avatar for a removed user in Mobile view and SE Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mobile-web, profile-picture

When a user was removed in web-view we can see an anonymous avatar picture in their posts, but in the mobile-view and android-app that avatar is missing.
It is simply showing their userid and it looks like something is missing.

It's my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to add the anonymous avatar in the [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) and [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app)

For sample I'm adding a [removed user's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250626/312043) in the three different views:

**Web-view:**

> [image: Anonymous avatar in web view]

**Mobile-web view:**

[image: Anonymous avatar in mobile view]

**Stack Exchange Android app view:**

[image: Anonymous avatar in SE app]