# "isanswered:no" returns questions with accepted answers

Tags: bug, search

According to the [Search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), `isanswered:no`

> returns only questions with no accepted or positively-scored answers

However, if I perform the following [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano+closed%3Ano+answers%3A1):

```
isanswered:no closed:no answers:1
```

I get questions back that have an accepted answer.

In all cases, the accepted answer is scored 0 or lower.

However, I expected to get back no questions with accepted answers.

This seems to be a bug to me.

If it's not a bug, how can I search for questions with these criteria?

- one or more answers with none scoring greater than 0, and
- no accepted answer

[Shadow Wizard points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257296/isansweredno-returns-questions-with-accepted-answers?noredirect=1#comment839161_257296) that I can do this:

```
isanswered:no closed:no answers:1 hasaccepted:0
```

But shouldn't `hasaccepted:0` be redundant to `isanswered:no`? If not, then the help text is misleading.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano+closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3A0

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Okay, that's a reasonable workaround. Thanks. But doesn't that also mean that `isanswered:no` isn't working as advertised?

Comment: Nope, the wording is confusing - must go now, if nobody else will answer will do it later, also explaining the true meaning of the help section you quoted.

Comment: This is similar to the general question I asked that includes why questions with accepted answers appear in "needs answer"... I'm guessing it's for a similar reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to m0sa,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250187/259867) the search parameter behavior is by design:

> It's just named badly. Consider thinking about it as hasAnswerWithScoreGreatherThanZero.

Naming aside, I actually prefer the current behavior, because it gives me more flexibility in search. I can combine `isanswered` and `hasaccepted` parameters to get any combination of "answer with positive score" and "accepted answer" I want:

- answer with positive score: yes, no, doesn't matter
- accepted answer: yes, no, doesn't matter

If `isanswered` automatically included `hasaccepted`, the search possibilities would be fewer.

So I think it's the help center that should be fixed. Until recently, the parameter was not documented there at all. After my request [The "isanswered" search parameter documentation is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250626/the-isanswered-search-parameter-should-be-documented) its description was added, but an incorrect one.